# The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I'm working on print functionality using socket programming in iOS. I'm using the following code to open streams and perform read and write operations. While opening streams, the delegate gets called for open event for both input and output streams. I also get a `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event where I perform a write operation and `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` event where I perform a read operation. Write operation is happening successfully for the first 2 times and after that I get bytes available event where I'm trying to perform a read operation. Everytime I get -1 as bytes read and getting a  `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred` event with a message

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer"

for `NSInputStream` followed by the same event for `NSOutputStream` as well while performing to write for the 3rd time. Sometimes I even get Broken Pipe error as well.

```
        CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"123.123.12.12",DEFAULT_LPR_PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
self.inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
self.outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
[self.outputStream setDelegate:self];

[self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[self.inputStream open];
[self.outputStream open];
```

Stream event handler - Delagate method code
Bytes read is always -1.

```
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
        if (theStream == inputStream) {
            
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len = 0;
            
            while ([self.inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [self.inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                NSLog(@"bytes read len --- :%d ",len);
                if (len > 0) {
                    
                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    
                    if (nil != output) {
                        NSLog(@"bytes value: %@", output);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        break;
```

Errror:

```
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.424 SPConnector[1936:907] stream:handleEvent: : <__NSCFInputStream: 0x1e07b0e0>
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.428 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred localizedDescription --- The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.430 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred domain --- NSPOSIXErrorDomain
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.431 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred Code --- :54
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.432 SPConnector[1936:907] stream:handleEvent: : <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x1e07b170>
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.433 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred localizedDescription --- The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.434 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred domain --- NSPOSIXErrorDomain
    2013-09-18 12:27:36.435 SPConnector[1936:907] NSStreamEventErrorOccurred Code --- :54
```

Can someone let me know what could be the reason for the issue?

Comment: Well "connection reset by peer" means the server closed the connection and there isn't much you can do about that.  You must have upset it somehow, but I think that's outside the scope of your question.  Are there logs on the server you can see why it left in a huff?

Comment: Sometimes I even get Broken Pipe error. It either shows Connection Reset By Peer or Broken Pipe error. I'm actually trying to connect to and MFD device. Have to check if there is any such option to verify the device logs.

Comment: What could be the reason for "Broken pipe" error?

Comment: I don't know where pipes come into it so no idea.

Comment: I also had problems with booth this errors. I did not reached to a solution properly about the connection reset by peer. But I can point you to some directions. On Broken Pipe, check whether you are sending data to fast to the socket. Put a 10 or 20ms delay between each write in the socket.

Comment: About connection reset by peer, it happens unexpectedly. What I am doing is just trying again. Broken Pipe is a EPIPE error which happens when you are trying to write to a socket in a invalid state for writing. Connection reset has several explanations but I can't say what would be your case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I receive the same message.
I call my service with "getHandShakeParameter" string,
but his name was "GetHandShakeParameter", with "G" in uppercase...

Problem solved ;)

Comment: could you explain what did you do a bit more?

Comment: In my case, i used wrong name of service, and i got the error in object.

Comment: By service, do u mean socket connection or something else?